# error code :1452 while inserting elements in table

Tags: mysql

Below is my table-

```
create table employee1(
 fname varchar(15) not null,
 minit char(15) ,
 lname varchar(15) not null,
 ssn char(9) not null,
 bdate date,
 address varchar(30),
 sex char,
 salary decimal(10,2),
 superssn char(9),
 dno int not null default 1,
 constraint emppk
 primary key (ssn),
 constraint empsupkerfk
 foreign key (superssn) references employee1(ssn) on delete set null on update cascade,
 constraint empdeptfk
 foreign key (dno) references department(dnumber) on delete set default on update cascade 
  );
```

Here is my insert statment-

```
insert into employee1 
(
fname,minit,lname,ssn,bdate,address,sex,salary,superssn,dno
 ) 
values (
'jhon','b','smith','123456789','1955-01-09','731 fondren,houston, tx','m','30000','33344555','5'
)
```

This is the error what I am getting-

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`employee`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`superssn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ssn`)

Comment: Removed the SQL Server tag as this query and error is from MySQL

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear and it means that you are trying to insert into `employee1`  a `superssn` value that does not exist in `employee`.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table.
>
> **It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation** that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.